# force.com IDE access to custom validation rules in a managed package object

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I am currently in sync between my org sandbox and my Force.com IDE in eclipse and can access custom/Standard objects and managed package objects in the Force.com IDE, we have created multiple custom validation rules for each managed package object, however in eclipse I can only access managed package validation rules wihtin a managed package object, same thing goes with Field sets. I access a managed package object from "Referenced Packages" Folder and then drill down to the object subfolder. is this a salesforce limitation when refreshing managed package metadata from Salesforce server, and is there a way to bypass that, I have red some articles about using package.xml - but I am not sure how to do that, can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, looks like Eclipse IDE's limitation.

In your project's folder you should see package.xml. You'll have to edit it manually. Try force adding the managed objects you need (including namespace) into the "Custom Object" section, like that:

[image]

Afterwards refresh "objects" directory from server, should bring in your object nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes it did bring the object by adding it to the package.xml, I have tried renaming a fieldset and saving it to the server, but the fieldset API Name and name got updated to the previous value and new fieldset was created with the updated name, I then tried to delete any fieldset lines from the object xml and save it, the fieldset did not get deleted, is this normal ?

Comment: Yes. Typically whatever you do with "Metadata API" (stuff used in Eclipse) is    about adding new components or changing existing ones. SF treated it as creation of new fieldset (because it saw new unique API name) and then tried to be "helpful" by bringing back from server fresh components including old one. You'll need to delete the old fieldset manually, I don't think you're ready for usage of "destructiveChanges.xml" and / or "Force.com Migration Tool" for scripted deployments. Eclipse will let you delete whole files (classes, pages, objects, reports), not really pieces of content...

Comment: Maybe you're more familiar with changesets? It's similar. There's no way a changeset will let you delete anything. Only adding/modifying. You need to replicate such manual steps like renaming in each environment you're going to deploy your change to. Trailheads like this might help: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/alm_deployment/units/alm_tools

Comment: Thanks, can I assume that Force.com Migration tool, would allow to change a Fieldset name/API Name, or am I supposed to delete using the destructivechanges.xml than create it again

Comment: It's same API so no, SF will treat it as new fieldset rather than editing of old one. You need to create new fieldset, update any places where it might be referenced to point to new name (Apex? VF?), delete old one with destructive changes. It's a pain. Much simpler to edit the API name manually ;) It's a shame that Tooling API doesn't support delete() for fieldsets: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fieldset.htm, would be easier. But you could try updating the DeveloperName there?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, that was very helpful